# change view structure without recreating it

Tags: postgresql

We actually have a views with nested dependencies in postgresql

- `T1(a,b,c,d,e,f)` : table
- `V1` : view of table T1 with columns a, b, c
- `V2` : view of V1 with column a, b

I'd like to add a column in view `V1`. In order to do that I must drop and recreate view `V1`.

However, since `V2` depends on `V1`, I also have to recreate it even though it doesn't use a new column.

Is there a way to add column to view without drop and recreate it and its dependents?

Comment: It's recommeneded to re-create a view when the underlying tables or views have changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your choice:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html

> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW is similar, but if a view of the same name already exists, it is replaced. The new query must generate the same columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the same column names in the same order and with the same data types), but it may add additional columns to the end of the list. The calculations giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.